# Trying to obtain File object from InputStream inside Tomcat for JSON Marshalling?

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jackson, inputstream

Am using Tomcat 7.0.5.5 along with JDK 1.6 on OS X...

Inside my Maven generated war file, I have a dir which looks like this (when the war file is unpacked):

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes/json/person.json
```

Am trying to obtain a File object from an input stream using a RESTful GET call:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/myservice/file/person.json
```

As one can see from the comments inside my uploadFile() method, the purpose of this is so I can
use it to marshal using Jackson:

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadJsonFileService {

    private final String JSON_DIR = "/json/";

    @GET
    @Path("/upload/{filename}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person uploadFile(@PathParam("filename") String fileName) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = 
              Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream inputStream = 
              classLoader.getResourceAsStream(JSON_DIR + fileName);

        // How to obtain a File object from inputStream?
        // e.g. How to assign it from inputStream to jsonFile?

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Person.class);
        return person;
     }  
 }
```

Is there a better way to do this (e.g. a different library such as Apache Commons IO FileUtil.getFile() method or org.apache.catalina.util URL)?

Comment: WEB-INF is invisible to the outside world and completely inappropriate as a place to upload files to. And why does a method named `uploadFile` return a `Person` object?

Comment: Don't know which version of Jackson you're using, but `readValue` that takes in an input-stream is what you need. http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.Class)

Comment: EJP because by returning a Person object, I can see the "produced" JSON string which is marshalled from Person object. srkavin, I am using readValue() - you didn't look at my code?

Comment: @AndrePerez `readValue` has a overloaded method to take in an input stream. Refer to the javadoc I have linked.